# How to create a batch file countdown timer in min:sec format that uses a variable as the finishing time and uses the current time as the start time?

Tags: variables, batch-file, timer

I am trying to create a countdown timer that is in `min`:`sec` format which uses a variable taken from a text document and uses it as the finish time and uses the current time (time the `.bat` was started) as the start time.
Currently I have this code which works and gets the time from the text document but I can't seem to figure out how to use get it to work.

Code:

```
@echo off

set CurrentTime=%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%

set /p StartTime=<"ResponseTime.txt"

echo.

echo %CurrentTime% %StartTIme%

echo.
```

Comment: well - you will need a loop and a check, if the endtime is reached. You can do the loop with `goto` and check the time with `if %currenttime% lss %starttime%`. Tell us, where you have problems.

Answer (score 5):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get end time
REM for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("ResponseTime.txt") do set /A endH=10%%a%%100, endM=1%%b%%100

REM Just for testing:
set endH=14
set endM=58

title Timer
mode con cols=16 lines=2

:synchronize
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%time%") do set /A "minutes=(endH*60+endM)-(%%a*60+1%%b-100)-1, seconds=159"

:wait
timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
echo Timer:  %minutes%:%seconds:~-2%
set /A seconds-=1
if %seconds% geq 100 goto wait
set /A minutes-=1, seconds=159, minMOD5=minutes %% 5
if %minutes% lss 0 goto :buzz
if %minMOD5% equ 0 goto synchronize
goto wait

:buzz
pause
```

Comment: Did this solution worked correctly? If so, you may select it as Best Answer, or up-vote it, or both (or leave a comment indicating if it not works, at least...)

Comment: Can you explain the `seconds=159`  and  `%seconds:~-2%`

Comment: Nevermind, I assume it has do do with displaying 2 zeros instead of one. For example **1:00** rather than **1:0**

Comment: how could I edit this so that it counts down from 13 minutes, and not over 700 hours?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a `timeout` function such as `timeout /t xx` where xx equals the time in seconds. If that is what you're looking for.

You can also do `timeout /t xx >nul` so that it won't display a message saying how many seconds you have left. If that is what you want then use the first one I showed. I hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Works perfect

```
@echo off
```

timeout /t 10>NUL
start chrome "https://google.com"

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop:

```
@echo off
set SecondsLeft=10
call :LOOP %SecondsLeft%
goto END

:LOOP
cls
set /a SecondsLeft=%SecondsLeft%-1
if %SecondsLeft% == 0 goto :eof
call echo Wait %SecondsLeft% seconds
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
goto LOOP

:END
pause
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).