# Countdown Timer Error

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a countdown timer but the timer doesn't count up or count down. Please Help ! it just shows +1.

```
:Plus    
echo-------------------------------------------------------------------------    
echo Please enter starting number...    
set /p time=%time%    
echo Please enter ending number...    
set /p etime=%etime%    
echo-------------------------------------------------------------------------    
echo.%time%    
set time=%time%     

:loop1    
set /p time=%time%+1    
if %time%==%etime% goto timesup1    
echo.%time%    
ping localhost -n 2 > nul    
goto loop1    

:timesup1    
echo.%etime%    
echo Time is Up!    
goto Opt    

(The Minus Option just shows the number typed then '-1')    
:Minus    
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------    
echo Please enter starting number...    
set /p time=%time%    
echo Please enter ending number...    
set /p etime=%etime%    
echo-------------------------------------------------------------------------   
echo %time%    
set time=%time%     

:loop2    
set /p time=%time%-1    
if %time%==%etime% goto timesup2    
echo %time%    
ping localhost -n 2 > nul    
goto loop2    

:timesup2    
echo %etime%    
echo Time is Up!    
goto Opt
```

Comment: Please have a look at this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23117993/1155650) and please post only the specific problem and the code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: its too complicated for me.. i'm new to coding batch files man.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here:

```
set /p time=%time%+1
```

you need `/a`, not `/p` to do calculations (see `set /?`)

Also you shouldn't set `%time%`, because it's a system variable used by windows. (use another name, like `sTime`(analogue to `eTime`)